# RDD constructed from parsed case class: serialization fails

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, rdd

I'm trying to understand how serialization in the case of a self constructed case class and a parser in a separate object works -- and I fail.

I tried to boil down the problem to:

- parsing a string into case classes
- constructing an RDD from those
- taking the first element in order to print it

```
case class article(title: String, text: String) extends Serializable {  
  override def toString = title + s"/" + text
}

object parser {
  def parse(line: String): article = {
    val subs = "</end>"
    val i = line.indexOf(subs)
    val title = line.substring(6, i)
    val text  = line.substring(i + subs.length, line.length)
    article(title, text)
  }  
}

val text = """"<beg>Title1</end>Text 1"
"<beg>Title2</end>Text 2"
"""

val lines = text.split('\n')
val res = lines.map( line => parser.parse(line) )
val rdd = sc.parallelize(res)

rdd.take(1).map( println )
```

I get a

`Job aborted due to stage failure: Failed to serialize task, not attempting to retry it. Exception during serialization: java.io.NotSerializableException`

Can a gifted Scala expert please help me -- just that I understand the interaction of serialization in workers and master -- how to fix the parser / article interaction such that serialization works?

Thank you very much.

Comment: ... the code works when I add `extends Serializable` to `object parser`. Still -- why ?

Comment: There are a lot of questions on this topic on this site, so I'm not going to provide a full answer, just search. But basically, spark works by sending all the code from the driver to executors. So every class, object, member you use must be `Serializable`, so it can be sent to the executors, along with the data that will be processed on those executors. Java does some things in the background to `Serializable` objects as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *map* function from *lines.map( line => parser.parse(line) )* you call *parser.parse* and parser it's your object which is not serializable. Spark internally uses partitions which are spread across the cluster. The *map* functions will be called on each partitions. Because the partitions are not on the same JVM process, the function that is called on each partition needs to be serializable, that is why your object parser has to obey the rule.